# Kotlin. How to map only non null values of list?

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, collections, kotlin-extension, kotlin-null-safety

I need to make some operations with my list.

For example I have list of `TestData`:

```
data class TestData (
    val value: Int?,
    val name: String
)
```

I need to map list of `TestData` to list of `String`. Here is my code:

```
 val names = listOfTestData
              .map { data -> getName(data.value) } <- Type mismatch. Required: Int, found Int?
              .distinct()
```

The problem is that the function `getName(value: Int)` accepts only a non nullable type. Can I somehow skip elements from `listOfTestData` whose `value` is null ?

I could filter the values before making a map, but I'll have to use inside the map `!!`, I'd like a more elegant solution.

```
 val names = listOfTestData
                  .filter { it.value != null }
                  .map { data -> getName(data.value!!) } 
                  .distinct()
```

Please tell me how can this be done without using `!!`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `filter`, you can `mapNotNull` to the `value`s. This is basically a `map`, but if the mapping function you provide returns `null`, the element is filtered out.

```
listOfTestData.mapNotNull { it.value }
    .map { getName(it) }
    .distinct()
```

This will go over the list 3 times. You can combine the `mapNotNull` and `map` by using a `?.let` on the `value`:

```
listOfTestData.mapNotNull { data -> data.value?.let { getName(it) } }.distinct()
```

Alternatively, use a sequence:

```
listOfTestData.asSequence()
    .mapNotNull { it.value }
    .map { getName(it) }
    .distinct()
    .toList()
```